# Why does the bulk modulus of water have a maximum at around 60-70ºC

Tags: water, material-science, fluid-statics

So I'm doing some water hammer analysis and was calculating bulk modulus of water as a function of temperature. I took the speed of sound and density of water as functions of temperature and calculated bulk modulus from there ($K=c^2\rho$). This yields the following graph:

[image: Bulk Modulus of water vs temperature @ 200 bar]

I was wondering what causes this behaviour. Is it the same reason why water is most dense at 4ºC? ie Is is to do with intermolecular bonds being stronger/weaker at a certain point. If it is related, why isn't the maximum at 4ºC for bulk modulus as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment not an answer, but I can't put pictures in a comment. If Adri agrees this could be edited into his question.

If we include the speed of sound and the density on the graph then the result is:

[image: Water properties]

All data is from the [Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/).

The density falls monotonically, so it's the maximum in the velocity that is related to the maximum in the bulk modulus and *vice versa*.

Comment: Thanks for the input. If you were too zoom in on the density I'm pretty sure there's an inflection point at about 4 degC. I'll edit the question to add these curves as well.

Comment: @AdriJamil: you keep saying *inflection* when you mean *maximum*. A [point of inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) is where the second derivative is zero. Yes, there is a maximum in the density at 4C.