# Why does the speed of sound in water not increase proportionately with temperature?

Tags: waves, temperature, acoustics, water, speed

I was just wondering, as per this graph (https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/sound-speed-water-d_598.html) why the speed of sound in water does not increase proportionately with temperature. Instead peaking at around 70C and decreasing. I think it's as the liquid starts transforming into a gas, and hence with the decreased elasticity the velocity decreases. As per this formula $v = \sqrt{K/\rho}$ with $K$ = elasticity. [image: a graph of speed of sound in water vs temperature]

Comment: Can you find any other sources, such as the CRC "Rubber Book" ?  It would also be useful to determine whether these data are for pure water vs. "normal" water full of dissolved gases.

Comment: Related, but no answer there:  [Why does the bulk modulus of water have a maximum at around 60-70ºC?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220834/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the bulk modulus of water have a maximum at around 60-70ºC](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220834/)

Comment: Interesting question. Looking around some ( https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1679903 ) it seem that people empirically fit an equation of state, and from the equation of state can then derive the sound velocity and compare with experimental sound velocity measurements, but they don't seem to explain physics of why the ratio of bulk modulus to density peaks around 70 degrees.